# Why am I getting this ImportError but function works anyway?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've got function which suppose to merge all .csv files from given directory into single data frame. Here it is:

```
import pandas as pd, os
from functools import reduce


def merge_csv_files(target_input_directory, target_output_path):
    list_of_data_files = os.listdir(target_input_directory)
    list_of_data_frames = []
    for file in list_of_data_files:
        new_df = pd.read_csv(target_output_path + '\\' + file)
        list_of_data_frames.append(new_df)
    df_merged = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on=['Data'], how='outer', sort=True),
                       list_of_data_frames)
    df_merged.to_csv(target_output_path + '\\' + 'merged.csv', index=False)
```

I'm getting the following ImportError:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'merge_csv_files'
```

Nevertheless my function seems to work correctly and I'm getting what I want, but the fact it returns an error is frustrating and I'd like to know the reason why this is happening.

Here is the directory tree:

[image]

Comment: if `file_merger.py` is in the same folder as jupyter noteboob then you could use `from file_merger import merge_csv_files` . Or maybe you have another function `merge_csv_files` in your notebook ?

Comment: You seem to have indentation issue there. How come your IDE didn't catch that? You seem to be using PyCharm.

Comment: @furas, I've tried that at 1st place. But it doesn't work this way, Portfolio_analysis.file_merger is the only way to get this function into the notebook.

Comment: @Asher, seems to be my fault while copying here. Corrected.

Comment: message `cannot import name 'merge_csv_files'` can means there is no `'merge_csv_files'` in imported file. Show again code which imports it. Or maybe you have two files `file_merger.py` and you have `'merge_csv_files'` only in one file but it tries to import file which doesn't have `'merge_csv_files'`

Comment: @furas when I'm doing the same in test.py (which I added to the same Portfolio_analysis directory) I'm not having any issues. Is there anything specific with Jupyter Notebook that has to be done in order to make function working?

Comment: Okay, I renamed file_merger.py and now it works.. Really, the named must have messed something.

Comment: sometimes it happens. (PL: czasami tak bywa :) )